# How do I increment a duplicate value (.001 to .002) in a loop

Tags: python, loops, duplicates, blender

I'm trying to write a Blender python script that duplicates an object and then updates the constraint so that `icosphere.002` has the same rotation as `Cube.002`
The loop needs to be repeated `421` times. Yet when it comes to the 10th loop, the value becomes `.0010` However, if I change the object restraint from `Cube.00` to `Cube.` it tries to look for `Cube.1`

```
import bpy

for i in range(1, 421):
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move_linked(
            OBJECT_OT_duplicate={"linked": True, "mode": 'TRANSLATION'},
            TRANSFORM_OT_translate={
                "value": (0, 0, 0),
                "constraint_axis": (False, False, False),
                "constraint_orientation": 'GLOBAL',
                "mirror": False,
                "proportional": 'DISABLED',
                "proportional_edit_falloff": 'SMOOTH',
                "proportional_size": 1,
                "snap": False,
                "snap_target": 'CLOSEST',
                "snap_point": (0, 0, 0),
                "snap_align": False,
                "snap_normal": (0, 0, 0),
                "gpencil_strokes": False,
                "texture_space": False,
                "remove_on_cancel": False,
                "release_confirm": False,
                "use_accurate": False
            })
    bpy.context.object.constraints["Copy Rotation"].target = (
        bpy.data.objects["Cube.00" + str(i)])
```

Comment: Instead of *00” + str(i)* use *%3d” % i*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `["Cube.{0:03}".format(i)]`, which will pad with the necessary number of zeroes (3 in this case), for example:

```
>>> "Cube.{0:03}".format(1)
'Cube.001'
>>> "Cube.{0:03}".format(12)
'Cube.012'
>>> "Cube.{0:03}".format(123)
'Cube.123'
```

In Python 3.6+ you can do like this (f-strings, see [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)):

```
f"Cube.{i:03}" # where i is your index variable
```

Comment: Thank you @hyst329. It works perfectly. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you aren't doing anything with the objects as you duplicate them, you don't need most of the default options that you are using. After the object is duplicated it will be the active object, so you can get it's numeric suffix from `bpy.context.object.name[-3:]`.

```
import bpy

cntxt = bpy.context
objlist = bpy.data.objects

for i in range(420):
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=True)
    suffix = cntxt.object.name[-3:]
    cntxt.object.constraints['Copy Rotation'].target = objlist['Cube.'+suffix]
```

You can name your first object `Cube.000` so that a suffix is always available.

Also of note is that operators [add extra overhead](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7358/935) so particularly with long loops it is preferred to work with data directly. Note that creating items directly gives you the item you created, where an operator leaves you relying on context, this means you depend less on naming and more on the exact item you create.

```
import bpy

scn = bpy.context.scene
objlist = bpy.data.objects
obj = objlist['Icosphere.000']

for i in range(420):
    new_obj = obj.copy()
    new_obj.data = obj.data.copy()
    scn.objects.link(new_obj)
    cr = new_obj.constraints.new('COPY_ROTATION')
    cr.target = objlist['Cube.{0:03}'.format(i)]
```